# will Including jquery more than once to a page create any issue ? why?

Tags: jquery

Let assume we have a layout , controller and view.

We are including jquery in layout, controller and view even if it is not needed.

Jquery is not working after that !! what will be wrong ?

What should be the best practise? Include it in layout and it will be automatically included all pages wuth that lay out.

Please suggest

Comment: I want to know what you think the controller is, such that you can *include jQuery in it*

Comment: from controller we can assign jquery filename to view  http://jquery.hohli.com/zf.html

Comment: don't worry about the down vote, I have leveled that. As far as the issue is concerned. Its still a little vague, but according to my experience scripts need to be clean and should be added in the head if thats what you are referring to the layout. Because unnecessary scripts and inclusions can be problematic as far as JS and jQuery is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

why not do a conditional include in all 3 places. So whatever loads jQuery first its OK as the other 2 would not include it again on your web page.

You can test if the jQuery object is defined or not. And include the script tag only if the jQuery object is not defined.

```
if(typeof(jQuery) == undefined){
    var jqS = document.createElement('script');
    jqS.src = 'jquery.min.js';
    jqS.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

someone wrote a script adressing this issue: http://www.purpleivy.net/web-design/development-tips/2010/03/including-jquery-multiple-times/

it allows you to include jquery multiple times without disrupting its functionality

Comment: As per my understanding , adding same file more than once makes no use and i dont need that. Am just trying to find why adding same file again and again is causing issues.